# Docker run cannot find executable "uwsgi"

Tags: python, docker, executable, uwsgi, falcon

I am trying to deploy a falcon app with Docker. Here is my Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:2-onbuild

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install uwsgi

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["uwsgi", "--http”, " :8000" , "—wsgi-file”, "falconapp.wsgi"]
```

However I keep getting error saying:

```
/bin/sh: 1: [uwsgi,: not found
```

I've tried running uwsgi in the local directory and it works well with the command:

```
uwsgi --http :8000 --wsgi-file falconapp.wsgi
```

Why is Docker not working in this case???

Here is the log, I'm pretty sure uwsgi is installed:

```
Step 5/7 : RUN pip install uwsgi
 ---> Running in 2df7c8e018a9
Collecting uwsgi
  Downloading uwsgi-2.0.17.tar.gz (798kB)
Building wheels for collected packages: uwsgi
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uwsgi: started
  Running setup.py bdist_wheel for uwsgi: finished with status 'done'
  Stored in directory: /root/.cache/pip/wheels/94/c9/63/e7aef2e745bb1231490847ee3785e3d0b5f274e1f1653f89c5
Successfully built uwsgi
Installing collected packages: uwsgi
Successfully installed uwsgi-2.0.17
Removing intermediate container 2df7c8e018a9
 ---> cb71648306bd
Step 6/7 : EXPOSE 8000
 ---> Running in 40daaa0d5efa
Removing intermediate container 40daaa0d5efa
 ---> 39c75687a157
Step 7/7 : CMD ["uwsgi", "--http”, " :8000" , "—wsgi-file”, "falconapp.wsgi"]
 ---> Running in 67e6eb29f3e0
Removing intermediate container 67e6eb29f3e0
 ---> f33181adbcfa
Successfully built f33181adbcfa
Successfully tagged image_heatmap:latest
dan@D-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/falconapp_api$ docker run -p 8000:80 small_runner
/bin/sh: 1: [uwsgi,: not found
```

Comment: you probably need to put `RUN pip install uwsgi` to your dockerfile under the `FROM`

Comment: @MazelTov Thank you for your response! Please see the updated post. I've added "RUN pip install uwsgi" and pretty sure it's installed. However I'm still getting the error

Answer (score 3, accepted):

very often you have to write the full patch for the executable. If you go to your container and run this command `whereis uwsgi` it will tell you it is at `/usr/local/bin/uwsgi` so your CMD should be in the same form:

```
CMD ["/usr/local/bin/uwsgi", "--http", " :8000" , "--wsgi-file", "falconapp.wsgi"]
```

Comment: Thank you!!!! This works.  Really appreciate it. Sorry my rep is below 15 and cannot upvote the answer

Comment: quick follow up question @MazelTov: just wondering, what command should I type in order to 'go to my container' ?

Comment: Also a follow up question:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076695/how-to-visit-the-my-falcon-app-after-docker-build-and-docker-run

Answer (score 1):

I see some incorrect syntax in CMD, please use this:

`CMD ["uwsgi", "--http", " :8000" , "--wsgi-file", "falconapp.wsgi"]`

some double quotes are incorrect and `--` is not before `wsgi-file` .

Comment: Hi! I have a follow-up question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49076695/how-to-visit-the-my-falcon-app-after-docker-build-and-docker-run
Would appreciate if you could take a look. Thanks!