# how to visit the my falcon app after docker build and docker run?

Tags: docker, uwsgi, falcon

As a follow up question of [Docker run cannot find executable "uwsgi"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49073975/docker-run-cannot-find-executable-uwsgi)
:

I have successfully executed `docker build` and `docker run` with the Dockerfile as:

```
FROM python:2-onbuild

# Set the working directory to /app
WORKDIR /app

# Copy the current directory contents into the container at /app
ADD . /app

# RUN pip install -r ./requirements.txt
RUN pip install uwsgi

EXPOSE 8000

CMD ["/usr/local/bin/uwsgi", "--http", " :8000" , "--wsgi-file", "falconapp.wsgi"]
```

I know it's running since I saw this output on terminal:

```
dacao@Das-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/bitbucket_2/heatmap_api$ docker run -p 8000:8000 image_heatmap
*** Starting uWSGI 2.0.17 (64bit) on [Tue Mar  6 01:57:52 2018] ***
compiled with version: 4.9.2 on 02 March 2018 19:46:35
os: Linux-4.9.60-linuxkit-aufs #1 SMP Mon Nov 6 16:00:12 UTC 2017
nodename: cc47a3a586e7
machine: x86_64
clock source: unix
pcre jit disabled
detected number of CPU cores: 4
current working directory: /app
detected binary path: /usr/local/bin/uwsgi
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI without its master process manager ***
your memory page size is 4096 bytes
detected max file descriptor number: 1048576
lock engine: pthread robust mutexes
thunder lock: disabled (you can enable it with --thunder-lock)
uWSGI http bound on  :8000 fd 4
spawned uWSGI http 1 (pid: 7)
uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:39275 (port auto-assigned) fd 3
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
Python version: 2.7.14 (default, Feb 17 2018, 09:47:19)  [GCC 4.9.2]
*** Python threads support is disabled. You can enable it with --enable-threads ***
Python main interpreter initialized at 0x1e966f0
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
your server socket listen backlog is limited to 100 connections
your mercy for graceful operations on workers is 60 seconds
mapped 72920 bytes (71 KB) for 1 cores
*** Operational MODE: single process ***
WSGI app 0 (mountpoint='') ready in 2 seconds on interpreter 0x1e966f0 pid: 1 (default app)
uWSGI running as root, you can use --uid/--gid/--chroot options
*** WARNING: you are running uWSGI as root !!! (use the --uid flag) *** 
*** uWSGI is running in multiple interpreter mode ***
spawned uWSGI worker 1 (and the only) (pid: 1, cores: 1)
```

And I'm sure Docker image is running:

```
dacao@Das-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/bitbucket_2/heatmap_api$ docker ps 
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                    NAMES
cc47a3a586e7        image_heatmap       "/usr/local/bin/uwsg…"   16 minutes ago      Up 17 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp   laughing_nightingale
dacao@Das-MacBook-Pro:~/Documents/bitbucket_2/heatmap_api$
```

Next, I want to check if my app is actually running. I tried the following url on my safari browser:

```
http://127.0.0.1:8000/healthcheck 
http://localhost:8000/healthcheck 
http://host-ip:8000/healthcheck
```

But neither worked. All are giving a 'fail to open page' error.
How to visit the my app?

Sorry I am rookie and really new to docker

UPDATE:

I tried `docker-machine ip` and it gives `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists` . I don't understand since I'm sure the image is running - I checked with `docker ps` and see the CONTAINER ID IMAGE , etc.

I also tried `docker-machine ls` and it gives empty list: `NAME ACTIVE DRIVER STATE URL SWARM DOCKER ERRORS`

Am I supposed to create a docker-machine by `docker-machine start` or `docker-machine create default` before I do `Docker run ...`  ?

Comment: you bind the container port `8000` to host port `80`. So you need to call `http://127.0.0.1`. you can also execute `docker ps -a` to see if the container is really running (not exited).

Comment: Did you try binding container port to host with -p flag? `docker run -p 8000:8000 myImage `

Comment: you can find this on your log: `uwsgi socket 0 bound to TCP address 127.0.0.1:41319 (port auto-assigned)`

Comment: @SebastianBrosch how would I use the TCP address 127.0.0.1:39275  ?   btw I re-edited my question, and this is the new log info

Comment: @LucasLago  Thank you for your reply! Yes, I tried running "docker run -p 8000:8000 image_heatmap"  see my new edits.

Answer (score 0):

Your HTTP server in container is running on port 8000, so if you want to see it on your host you must publish port with this pattern:

`docker run -p <host-port>:<container-port> smaller_runner`

So, you must run this if you want to visit your container on your host on port 8000:

`docker run -p 8000:8000 smaller_runner`

then you can check one of this urls:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/healthcheck 
http://localhost:8000/healthcheck 
http://host-ip:8000/healthcheck

if you want to run container on background use `-dit` for it:

`docker run -dit --name test -p 8000:8000 smaller_runner`

Comment: HI, thank you for your answer! I tried exactly your suggestions (please see my new edits in the question.)  However I still get 'fail to open page' for all three urls....

Comment: Try this in you terminal to find out your host ip: `docker-machine ip` then goto this url in your browser: `<your-machine-ip>:8000`

Comment: I tried `docker-machine ip` and it gives `Error: No machine name(s) specified and no "default" machine exists` .  I don't understand since I'm sure the image is running - I checked with `docker ps` and see the CONTAINER ID        IMAGE , etc.

Comment: I also tried `docker-machine ls` and it gives empty list: `NAME ACTIVE DRIVER STATE URL SWARM DOCKER ERRORS`

Comment: Am I supposed to create a docker-machine by `docker-machine start` or `docker-machine create default` before I do `Docker run ...`  ?

Answer (score 0):

Upon looking at the startup logs, looks like the problem is with **uWSGI** configuration.

It seems that the server is listening only from `127.0.0.1` which is the localhost inside the docker container. Have you tried setting the `HOST` to `0.0.0.0` in your **uWSGI** configuration? And don't forget to bind the port to the host machine.